# How should I fix this

Tags: java

Ok guys Im stuck with this getting 10 errors, can someone help me? These errors are asking about identifier and stuff. Im stuck on this for quite a while now and just dont know where i went wrong? Did I not setup the variables right or what? This the errors:

DemoSquare.java:36: error:  expected
   public Square(Height, Width)
                       ^

DemoSquare.java:36: error:  expected
   public Square(Height, Width)
                              ^

DemoSquare.java:36: error: ';' expected
   public Square(Height, Width)
                               ^

DemoSquare.java:39: error:  expected
       square_width= width;
                   ^

DemoSquare.java:42: error: class, interface, or enum expected
   public int getheight()
          ^

DemoSquare.java:47: error: class, interface, or enum expected
   }
   ^

DemoSquare.java:48: error: class, interface, or enum expected
   public int getwidth(){
          ^

DemoSquare.java:50: error: class, interface, or enum expected
   }
   ^

DemoSquare.java:51: error: class, interface, or enum expected
   public int computeSurfaceArea()
          ^

DemoSquare.java:54: error: class, interface, or enum expected
         surfaceArea = (getheight() * getwidth());
         ^

DemoSquare.java:55: error: class, interface, or enum expected
         return surfaceArea;
         ^

DemoSquare.java:57: error: class, interface, or enum expected
   }
   ^
12 errors

Tool completed with exit code 1

```
`import java.util.Scanner;
public class DemoSquare
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   //Prints asking for Square user input
    System.out.println("Please enter square height: ");
    int square_height = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter square width: ");
    int square_width = input.nextInt();

   //Prints asking for Cube user input
    System.out.println("Please enter cube height: ");
    int cube_height = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter cube width: ");
    int cube_width = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter cube depth: ");
    int cube_depth = input.nextInt();

    //Prints for Square Area :)
    Square aSquare = new Square(square_height, square_width);
    System.out.println("Square Area is: "+ square.computeSurfaceArea());
    Cube aCube = new Cube(cube_height, cube_width, cube_depth);
    System.out.println("Cube Area is: " + cube.computeSurfaceArea());

}

}

public class Square
 {
  int square_height = 0;
  int square_width = 0;

  public Square(height, width) (
   square_height= height;
   square_width= width;
  }

  public int getheight()
 {

    return square_height;

  }

    public int getwidth(){

     return square_width;
  }

     public int computeSurfaceArea()
  {
  int surfaceArea = square_height * square_width;
     surfaceArea = (getheight() * getwidth());
     return surfaceArea;

   }

   }
     public class Cube extends Square
  {

       int cube_height = 0;
       int cube_width = 0;
       int cube_depth = 0;


        public Cube(int height, int width, int depth) {
        super(cube_height, cube_width);
        cube_depth = depth;
   }

    @Override
     public int getcube_width() {
      return cube_width;
  }

  @Override
     public int getcube_height() {
      return cube_Height;
  }

  public int getcube_depth() {
      return cube_depth;
  }

  @Override
  public int computeSurfaceArea() {

      int cube_surface_area = (cube_height * cube_width * cube_depth);

      return cube_surface_area;
  }
  }`
```

Comment: Here they are: 1. Be more specific 2. Be more specific 3. Be more specific 4. Be more specific 5. Be more specific 6. Be more specific 7. Be more specific 8. Be more specific 9. Be more specific 10. Be more specific

Comment: I'm voting to close. Read the Help Center.

Comment: Remember that Java is case-sensitive.

Comment: Seriously, we can't read your mind and see the compiler errors you're seeing, and playing a guessing game isn't something that a lot of people want to do. Also, read those compiler errors carefully. If you aren't working with generics they should be quite clear.

Comment: The compiler isn't lying to you.  You have to be consistent with your variable name throughout its scope or you'll run into situations like this.

Comment: These are the errors:

Comment: Stop. Don't put them in the comments. Update your question.

Comment: And make them readable, for heaven's sake. No one wants to read a blob of text. Use the preview window.

Comment: @user3580294 don't write the entire comment in uppercase. It looks like if you were really angry.

Comment: @Christian I felt shouting might have been appropriate to get OP to update the question instead of putting info in the comments, but OK. I'll change that. (I might have been a little mad after seeing that a bit too frequently)

Comment: sorry here I fixed it

Comment: You would get the best hint by properly indenting your code. Please put some effort into your code and into your question. Read the Help Center.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis  Please ccut me some slack. I just joined this place and really don't know how to use everything yet, just this once, I promise I'll clean up my act the next time around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I notice is here,

```
public Square(height, width)
```

Should be

```
public Square(int height, int width)
```

The next thing I notice is

```
public int computeSurfaceArea()
{
  // int surfaceArea = square_height * square_width;
  // surfaceArea = (getheight() * getwidth());
  return getheight() * getwidth();
}
```

Finally, I suggest you follow standard Java naming practices; `getHeight()` and `getWidth()`, and then `getHeight()`, `getWidth()` and `getDepth()` in `Cube`. Also it might be better to call it `getSurfaceArea()`. Consistency is good (and remember the [maintenance programmer](http://www.crsr.net/Links/index.html)).

Note this applies also to your `Cube` constructor, for a quick fix -

```
public Cube(int height, int width, int depth) {
    super(height, width); // cube_height, cube_width are defaulting to 0.
    cube_depth = depth;
    cube_height = height; // <-- you called it cube_height, not just height.
    cube_width = width;
}
```

Comment: @ElliottFrish is the computeSurfaceArea grey text what your suggesting or where I was wrong?

Comment: @user3761973 I was commenting out your existing code. You don't need a temporary variable, or to compute the surface area twice per call. Just return the result.

Comment: @ElliottFrish Thanks I brought it down to just 2. It says it cannot find symbol                                            System.out.println("Cube Area is: " +  cube.computeSurfaceArea());